# Testing Hoodie.js app on mobile: What URL to use?

Tags: mobile, mobile-safari, ip-address

Previously I was testing my app on mobile by using my IP followed by whichever localhost I was on. For instance, if I was on localhost:3000, I would plug 172.20.10.2:3000 into my mobile safari URL bar to view my app on mobile.

Now that I've installed hoodie.js, and I'm starting up my server with "hoodie start" in the command line, I've been unable to test on mobile using the same method.

This is what I see in my terminal when the server starts:

> CouchDB started: 127.0.0.1:6003 
>   Waiting for CouchDB [---*--]
>   SUCCESS  run static hook: server.pack.pre WWW:
>   127.0.0.1:6001 Admin:  127.0.0.1:6002

I've tried the above URLs and also these URLS:

172.20.10.2:6003
172.20.10.2:6001
172.20.10.2:6002

and each time mobile Safari says the server cannot be found. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that Hoodie is not accessible from outside your computer is that Hoodie binds to the private `127.0.0.1`address. You can overwrite that by setting the `HOODIE_BIND_ADDRESS` environment variable.

On a Mac, it's as simple as `HOODIE_BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0 hoodie start`, I'm not sure how the syntax is on windows

Comment: That worked on my Mac - thanks Gregor! So, for me, if I fire up my server with 'HOODIE_BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0 hoodie start' in the terminal, I can access the app on mobile Safari by plugging my IP followed by ':6001'